# Download file from link in R

Tags: csv, http, download

I would like to download a csv from this link -> https://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=NASDAQ&render=download

If you click on this link, you will download a csv.

How can I do to download this file to my folder?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
library(RCurl)



URL      <- "https://www.nasdaq.com/screening/companies-by-industry.aspx?exchange=NASDAQ&render=download"
destfile <- "nasdaq.csv"
download.file(URL, destfile)
```

Very Easy!

Sorry