# Download zip file to R when download link ends in '/download'

Tags: r, url, download, zip

My issue is similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53355423/download-file-from-link-in-r), but the solution suggestion does not appear applicable.

I have a lot of zipped data stored an online server (B2Drop), that provides a download link with the extension `"/download" instead of ".zip"`. I have been unable to get the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23899525/using-r-to-download-zipped-data-file-extract-and-import-csv), to work.

I have created a test download page https://b2drop.eudat.eu/s/K9sPPjWz3jxtXEq, where the download link https://b2drop.eudat.eu/s/K9sPPjWz3jxtXEq/download can be obtained by right clicking the download button. Here is my script:

```
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("https://b2drop.eudat.eu/s/K9sPPjWz3jxtXEq/download",temp, mode="wb")
data <- read.table(unz(temp, "Test_file1.csv"))
unlink(temp)
```

When I run it, I get the error:

> download.file("https://b2drop.eudat.eu/s/K9sPPjWz3jxtXEq/download",temp, mode="wb")
> trying URL 'https://b2drop.eudat.eu/s/K9sPPjWz3jxtXEq/download'
> Content type 'application/zip' length 558 bytes
> downloaded 558 bytes

> data <- read.table(unz(temp, "Test_file1.csv"))
> Error in open.connection(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection
> In addition: Warning message:
> In open.connection(file, "rt") :
> cannot locate file 'Test_file1.csv' in zip file 'C:\Users\User_name\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpMZ6gXi\file3e881b1f230e'

which typically indicates a problem with the working directory where R is looking for the file. In this case that should be the temp `wd`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your internal path is wrong. You can use `list=TRUE` to list the files in the archive, analogous to the command-line utility's `-l` argument.

```r
unzip(temp, list=TRUE)
#                  Name Length                Date
# 1 Test/Test_file1.csv    256 2021-09-27 10:13:00
# 2 Test/Test_file2.csv    286 2021-09-27 10:14:00
```

Better than `read.table`, though, use `read.csv` since it's comma-delimited.

```r
data <- read.csv(unz(temp, "Test/Test_file1.csv"))
head(data, 3)
#   ID Variable1 Variable2 Variable Variable3
# 1  1         f     54654       25        t1
# 2  2         t       421       64        t2
# 3  3         x      4521       85        t3
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you @r2evans!

Comment: So the script works when I am retrieving zipped files, but I can't get it to work to download stand-alone files (xlsx, csv, or text). Excel example [here](https://b2drop.eudat.eu/s/Z9jgK98Wmi9GDz5) code: `data <- openxlsx::read.xlsx("Test_file_excel.xlsx")`.  It indicates that the file doesn't exist. I'm assuming the file name is indicated as something other than the excel name?

Comment: To what directory did you download it? Is that the same as `getwd()`? That file opens fine for me, so it's likely a working-directory problem.

Comment: I'm using exactly the same method as before (creating a temp doc, same wd), the only change is the url and the read.xlsx() code excluding the unzip function. I'll mess around with the wd to see if I can find the solution, thank you for the suggestion.